# How do I add a port number to a action=" " in form submit htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a form that needs to be submitted on a certain port

its currently submitting on

```
http://10.26.50.217/wapi/login
```

and it needs to be submitted on

```
http://10.26.50.217:8010/wapi/login
```

Is there a way to do this in the htaccess file?
This is what I tried with no luck.

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^8010$
RewriteRule ^/wapi/login/(.*[^/])/?$ 10.26.50.217:8010/wapi/login/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just specify a valid URL:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^8010$
RewriteRule ^/wapi/login/(.*[^/])/?$ http://10.26.50.217:8010/wapi/login/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Well, obviously it _first_ submits to the URL you tell it to. The redirection takes place only _after_ the request has reached the http server. That sends the redirection, which _should_ be followed by your client. If it does however depends not on the server, but on your client, whatever that is. This simply is how such redirections work. Question: why don't you specify that URL with the port number in the first place, why do you rely on that redirection instead?